# Novel about a dying sun and a generation ship

Tags: story-identification

I've been trying to remember the name of this novel I read many years ago and it's driving me crazy. It's possible that I'm mixing two different novels together in my head but I don't think so.

The story followed several plot lines but they all revolved around the Earth's sun dying- one followed the construction of a ship that was being sent into the sun to try and find out what was happening. I remember there was a lot of description of the heat shielding they were using and talking about how it would take the ship many, many years to reach the center.
The other plot line I remember was on a generation ship where things had gone wrong somehow. One member of the original crew(I think he was augmented in some way) was leading a group of second or third generation decendants who had forgotten all about earth and technology.
The novel spanned thousands of years.

If this sounds familiar to anyone please let me know. Thank you so much!

Comment: I advise going to https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to get some prompts for better details that you can [edit] into your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is almost certainly *[Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(Baxter_novel))* by Stephen Baxter, part of his *Xeelee* sequence.

> The novel tells the story of the end of the universe and the saving of
> mankind from its destruction. Two parallel plots are followed
> throughout the novel: that of Lieserl, an AI exploring the interior of
> the sun, and that of the Great Northern, a generation ship on a
> five-million-year journey.
>
> The AI Lieserl is abandoned for five million years, leaving her to
> observe the sun's interior. She discovers dark matter-based life,
> which she names "photino birds". These birds gradually drain the
> energy from the core of a star, ending fusion and causing premature
> aging into a stable red giant—the birds' preferred habitat, as it has
> no risk of going supernova and destroying them.
>
> A generation ship is sent with one end of a wormhole to explore the
> future and investigate the whereabouts of Michael Poole. It will be a
> round-trip journey, returning to the solar system after five million
> years, though only a thousand years will elapse on board, due to
> relativistic time dilation effects. The crew is broken into three
> factions—the primitives, the virtuals, and a survivalist faction,
> Superet. Among the factions, the primitives are a eugenics project for
> Garry Uvarov who hopes to lengthen the lives of humanity without the
> use of Anti-Senescence (anagathic or life-extension) technology. The
> Superet faction relies heavily on failing technology and maintains a
> totalitarian government which refuses to acknowledge the existence of
> other decks on the ship; the virtuals remain aloof.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy!